# openMP code with C++ class data member not working

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, openmpi

I am trying to parallelize a 'for' loop in the class member function. I want one of the private data member to be treated as thread-private variable. Here is my code:

```
// Class declaration 

// MyClass.hpp file
class MyClass 
{
  // public data and function members
 public:   
  struct myVar {
    int g_data[576];
    int h_data[576];
  };

void myFun();

// Copy Constructor
  inv_parfor(inv_parfor const&) = delete;

// Assignment Operator
  inv_parfor& operator= (inv_parfor const&) & = delete;

private:
myVar avar;

};

// MyClass.cpp file

// Constructor 
MyClass ::MyClass() :  
  myVar()
  
{
  
}

void MyClass::myFun(){
// some code
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2 > omp_get_max_threads() ? omp_get_max_threads() : 2) private(avar))
{

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    smax = (static_cast<int>(i) + 1.0) * 25.3 * 100.0;    
    k = t_size[0] * t_size[1];
    for (b_n = 0; b_n < k; b_n++) {
      avar.g_data[b_n] = avar.t_data[b_n] * smax;
    }
// some code
}


}
```

However, I'm not able to compile this code. I am getting the compilation error: only a variable or static data member can be used in a data-sharing clause.

Is this not allowed? could anyone please suggest solution for this?

I tried to declare the data member 'avar' as static:
static myVar avar;

But then I am getting the compilation error: cannot initialize static class data via constructor

Comment: Only the msvc compiler (supports a very old OpenMP 2.0 only) gives this error message (see on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Y6rsfqo8c)), to solve your problem use clang or g++ compiler (both supports much newer OpenMP standards 5.0/4.5). Note that you can use clang in Visual Studio as well.

Comment: @Laci Thanks, I am able to compile the code using MinGW. is there any workaround for msvc?

Comment: Define a local `avar` variable in the parallel region, like [here](https://godbolt.org/z/767shaMr9).